# Converting JQuery Vars/Funcs to Vanilla JS Vars/Funcs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, legacy-code

I'm currently working on some legacy code and converting all the old JQuery to Vanilla/ES6 Javascript.  I'm running into some quirky JQuery syntax that I can't get a clear explanation of.  First, I've got a function that looks like this:

`(function($) { Do something } (jQuery);`

Is there anything different from this function than a standard function declaration? Like so:

`const myFunc = () => ( Do something )`

Secondly, I've got some oddly named vars in my code.  One in particular looks like this:

`$_some_weird_var_value = "";`

Whats the deal with the dollar sign? It just indicates JQuery, but if  wanted to convert this var to a regular one, I'd just drop the dollar sign, right?  The underscores in the naming makes me think this is some sort of constant, so maybe this becomes something like this:

`const _some_weird_var_value = "";`

Any and all input is welcome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> (function($) { Do something } (jQuery);
> ```

That is an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) (a function that is called immediately). It has nothing to do with jQuery (other than that jQuery is passed as an argument to it).

> ```
> const myFunc = () => ( Do something )
> ```

That's an arrow function (assigned to a constant), not a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function).

> Whats the deal with the dollar sign?

As far as JavaScript (or jQuery for that matter) is concerned, it is just a character you are allowed to use in a variable name.

The variable `$` is the traditional short variable name used to hold the jQuery function.

Variables with names which start with a `$` are traditionally used to hold instances of the jQuery object (e.g. `$body = $("body");`).

> The underscores in the naming makes me think this is some sort of constant

It's a constant if it is declared with `const` in the first place. Your example doesn't show the declaration of the variable (unless it is an implicit global, which should be avoided, and which would be banned in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)).

Answer (score 2):

```
(function($) { Do something } (jQuery);
```

This is just a plain old immediatly invoked function expression, a.k.a. IIFE. You use it to create a closure, for instance, preventing variables being declared on the global scope.

The last set of parentheses are you passing in variables from the current scope, the first set, is you passing those into the function that's going to be executed, you can rename those there, there is nothing special about the dollar sign.

For instance, this would be valid.

```
(function (foo) {
     // foo === window.jQuery
})(jQuery);
```

The difference between an IIFE and a standard function declaration is that the function inside an IIFE is declared within an enclosed scope, i.e. a closure, whereas a standard function declaration is declared within the scope its declared in.

Lastly, variables beginning with a $ is a jQuery 'standard', there is nothing special about that in terms of the Javascript language.